# How Should This SQL with Left Joins be Written in Access 2007?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a sql statement with multiple left joins that I cannot get to work in Access 2007, the message stating,

> JOIN expression not supported

```
SELECT
  Foo.A,
  Bar.B,
  Baz.C,
  Bat.D
FROM
  Foo
LEFT JOIN
  Bar ON Foo.BarId = Bar.BarId
LEFT JOIN
  Baz ON Foo.BazId = Baz.BazId
LEFT JOIN
  Bat ON Foo.BatId = Bat.BatId

WHERE 
  Foo.CriteriaColumn = 1
```

What is the correct format for Access 2007?

Comment: This is not an Access issue, but a Jet/ACE issue. Access has no SQL, but Jet/ACE does. I find it easiest to let Access write the join -- paste your non-working SQL into the query designer's SQL view, remove all the joins, so you have "FROM Foo, Bar, Baz, Bat" then you use the QBE to create the joins visually, and then flip back to SQL view to see how Access writes it. Keep in mind that just surrounding the nested JOIN ON pairs won't necessarily get you correct results, nor Jet/ACE-compliant joins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been a while since I did joins in Access, but enclosing each join expression separately in parentheses should do the trick:

```
SELECT
  Foo.A,
  Bar.B,
  Baz.C,
  Bat.D
FROM
  ((Foo
LEFT JOIN
  Bar ON Foo.BarId = Bar.BarId)
LEFT JOIN
  Baz ON Foo.BazId = Baz.BazId)
LEFT JOIN
  Bat ON Foo.BatId = Bat.BatId
WHERE 
  Foo.CriteriaColumn = 1
```

Comment: +1, I was just about to post the same thing. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA012314891033.aspx?pid=CH100728991033

Comment: Thanks for the link Chris! I'll just remove the OUTER bit since that seems to be T-SQL only after all. :-)