# Cannot figure out Access SQL Syntax Error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to write this query in Microsoft Access SQL and for the life of me I cannot figure out the syntax error in the code.

```
SELECT base.study_group, base.NPI,inv.log_date AS invite_date, rec.log_date as
recieved_date, rej.log_date as reject_date
FROM CODAAC_master AS base
LEFT JOIN Pre_Log AS inv ON base.NPI = inv.NPI AND inv.tracking_event='INVA'
LEFT JOIN Pre_Log AS rec ON base.NPI = rec.NPI AND rec.tracking_event='RECA'
LEFT JOIN Pre_Log AS rej ON base.NPI = rej.NPI AND rej.tracking_event='REJA'
WHERE base.study_year = '2013'
ORDER BY base.study_group, base.NPI;
```

The error I get back is:

```
"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression"
```

Comment: Use the query design window. You are short of parentheses. Access needs them on joins.

Answer (score 3):

MS Access requires parentheses around multiple joins:

```
SELECT base.study_group, 
  base.NPI,
  inv.log_date AS invite_date, 
  rec.log_date as recieved_date, 
  rej.log_date as reject_date
FROM ((CODAAC_master AS base
LEFT JOIN Pre_Log AS inv 
  ON base.NPI = inv.NPI AND inv.tracking_event='INVA')
LEFT JOIN Pre_Log AS rec 
  ON base.NPI = rec.NPI AND rec.tracking_event='RECA')
LEFT JOIN Pre_Log AS rej 
  ON base.NPI = rej.NPI AND rej.tracking_event='REJA'
WHERE base.study_year = '2013'
ORDER BY base.study_group, base.NPI;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add parenthesis between the joins as it is essential on MS Access. (*This is optional on other RDBMS*)

```
SELECT  base.study_group, 
        base.NPI,
        inv.log_date AS invite_date, 
        rec.log_date as recieved_date, 
        rej.log_date as reject_date
FROM  ((CODAAC_master AS base LEFT JOIN Pre_Log AS inv 
            ON base.NPI = inv.NPI AND inv.tracking_event='INVA')
        LEFT JOIN Pre_Log AS rec 
            ON base.NPI = rec.NPI AND rec.tracking_event='RECA')
        LEFT JOIN Pre_Log AS rej 
            ON base.NPI = rej.NPI AND rej.tracking_event='REJA'
WHERE base.study_year = '2013'
ORDER BY base.study_group, base.NPI;
```

- [Extra Source: **Multiple LEFT JOINs in MS Access**](http://nm1m.blogspot.com/2007/10/multiple-left-joins-in-ms-access.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added the parenthesis but now it is saying that the JOIN expression is not supported.

Comment: what version of ms access you are using/

Comment: your question is the on this [MS Access 2007 Multiple Left Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527752/how-should-this-sql-with-left-joins-be-written-in-access-2007), try to execute the updated statement